# OpenVZ Web panel: no such file to load when add physical server

Tags: openvz, lxc

I'm trying to use on my (testing) lxc server. I've on my server "potager.local":

> root@potager:~# lxc-list
>   RUNNING
>
> FROZEN
>
> STOPPED
>   web

I've installed [OpenVZ Web Panel](https://code.google.com/p/ovz-web-panel/) on it and it run correctly. So web interface is accessible with http:// 127.0.0.1:3000.

But, when i try to add a physical server with:

- host: potager.local
- root password: **************
- port: 7767

A message is returned:

> Internal error: no such file to load -- net/ssh

Answer (score 0):

Are you really sure about LXC support in OpenVZ WebPanel? AFAIK it need only kernel and userspace from OpenVZ project.